ActivityHistory via Analytic cloud
Can we query all ActivityHistory not limited to account contact and other objects via Analytics cloud and get them by making an API call from a third-party system?
In Salesforce we need to use the child query to get the ActivityHistories which is limited to the Contact object.
Example:
[SELECT Name, (SELECT Subject, ActivityType FROM ActivityHistories) FROM Contact]

If we directly try to query we get the error:-

INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION: entity type ActivityHistory does not
support query.

But if I want to go for more objects like Account, and Opportunity the SOQL count will increase for other child querys.
